# Find if a string is empty

Tags: c#, string

I have a homework to do and I have a string initialized like this:

```
string s= "abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,,";
```

I have to check if near comma exists a char or there isn't anything. I have tried this code:

```
do{
    if (s==','){
        count++;
        if (count==3)
            if(s++!=',')
                MessageBox.Show("Substring not empty");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Substring empty");
    }
}while(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```

but I have two errors:

```
Error   1   Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'char'
Error   2   Operator '++' cannot be applied to operand of type 'string'
```

So, how can I verify if after the comma there is a char?

Comment: `s` is a string, but you are trying to compare it with a character. Also, according to the error, it seems that `count` is a `string`, not an int. Even without the compilation errors, that code will run forever since you are always checking the same string, without removing letters from it, thus the `String.IsNulOrEmpty` will always return `false`.

Comment: `string.Split` is what you should start with. If the resulting array contains an entry in it which is blank then you had two commas adjacent, or a comma at the start or end of the string.

Comment: We can check if we have either `",,"` fragment or string starts / ends with `','`

Comment: It you want to compare **characters**, use `s[indexpositionhere]` rather than `s`. You could compare that to `,` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is homework, so something "advanced" like LINQ wouldn't be what I would turn in:

```
var somethingIsEmpty = str.Split(',').Any(e => e.Length==0);
```

Think about it a bit more, write some comments, write code underneath them:

```
//get the string 

//split the string on commas, don't enable RemoveEmptyEntries

//use a loop to iterate through the whole splitted array

  //if any element of the array has a zero length, show a message
```

When you're learning, this is a better way to code; write your algorithm in the language you think in, as comments.. Then translate the comments to code, end up with nicely commented code, that works. Failing to write comments means you run the risk of forgetting where you're going, what you're doing, what your algorithm is, and you revert to coding by trial and error without thinking about what you're actually doing

Having written the algorithm in comments, I can translate to code easily like this:

```
//get the string
string str = "a,b,c,,d";

//split the string on commas, don't enable RemoveEmptyEntries
string[] bits = string.Spilt(',');

//use a loop to iterate through the whole splitted array
for(int i = 0; i <= bits.Length; i++){

  //if any element of the array has a zero length, show a message
  if(bits[i].Length > 0)
    MessageBox.Show("Element " + i + " has zero length");
}
```

**This code contains three deliberate errors**. I don't want to rob you of the learning opportunity you're supposed to be acquiring here; you need to think about this still- don't just hand this code in - work through it, think about it, fix the errors

Or from Dmitry's comment, investigate these:

```
yourstring.Contains(",,");
yourstring.StartsWith(",");
yourstring.EndsWith(",");
```

These return Booleans, if any of them are true, then your string is out of spec

Comment: Maybe change this: `str.Split().Any(e => e.Length==0)` to this: `str.Split(',').Any(e => e.Length==0)`?

Comment: Thanks @npinti - I remembered you can use Split() with no arguments but I forgot that it splits on whitespaces in that configuration, whereas I thought commas were one of the default characters

Answer (score 1):

`'a'` -- > is a char

`"a"` -- > is a string

This error messages very clear.

Error   1   Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'char'

-- > **s** is a string variable but **','** is a char value. You can't compare these two

Error   2   Operator '++' cannot be applied to operand of type 'string'

--> where is the **content** variable ? and **content** is it numerical value ?

this code won't work.

Please try this

```
string s = "abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,,";

        string[] s2 = s.Split(',');

        for (int i = 0; i < s2.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s2[i]))
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Partition FULL",i.ToString());
            else
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Partition Empty", i.ToString());
        }


        Console.Read();
```

output

```
0 Partition FULL
1 Partition FULL
2 Partition FULL
3 Partition FULL
4 Partition FULL
5 Partition Empty
6 Partition Empty
```

Comment: This situation depends on the point of view. Sometimes the best way to learn is to study the code

Answer (score 0):

**First error**: `s` is a `string`. When you do `s==','`, you are comparing a `string` to a `char`, because `','` is a `char`.

**Second error**: You cannot apply `++` operator to a `string`. You should access single characters of a `string` in the same way as you would access an item from an `array` (`s[0]` would get you the 1st character etc.).

**Solution to both problems**: initialize an `int` counter and use it to go through the `string` character by character by using `i++` and `s[i]`.

Here is a quick snippet:

```
int i = 0;
while(i < s.Length) {
    // get the current character
    char c = s[i];
    if(c == ',') {
        // current character is a comma
        // check if the previous character was also a comma OR if the current position is at the start/end of the string
        if(i == 0 || s[i - 1] == ',' || i == s.Length - 1) {
            MessageBox.Show("Substring empty");
        } else {
            MessageBox.Show("Substring not empty");
        }
    }
    // advance by one position
    ++i;
}
```